# Forward and Backward RegEx Lookups

Tags: c#, regex

How can i get the value of nserver without the dot at the end?

It tried this Regex, but i cannot get rid of the last dot.

```
nserver:(\s*)(?<Value>(\S*))
```

This is the data in which I search

```
% By submitting a query to RIPN's Whois Service
% you agree to abide by the following terms of use:
% http://www.ripn.net/about/servpol.html#3.2 (in Russian) 
% http://www.ripn.net/about/en/servpol.html#3.2 (in English).

domain:        WEBMONEY.RU
nserver:       ns.molot.ru.
nserver:       ns.relsoftcom.ru.
nserver:       ns.relsoft.ru.
state:         REGISTERED, DELEGATED, VERIFIED
org:           "Computing Forces" CJSC
registrar:     RU-CENTER-REG-RIPN
admin-contact: https://www.nic.ru/whois
created:       1998.04.24
paid-till:     2014.05.01
free-date:     2014.06.01
source:        TCI

Last updated on 2014.02.02 00:06:43 MSK
```

I want this as result

```
ns.molot.ru
```

I'm using these options

```
 RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, isn't your regex supposed to be:

```
(?<=nserver:)(\s*)(?<Value>.*(?=.\r\n))
```

? (Carriage return before newline/linefeed)

You could perhaps escape the dot, and turn the greedy `.*` into lazy `.*?`, but a simpler way without the lookahead could be:

```
(?<=nserver:)\s*(?<Value>\S+)\.
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yF7zK8)

---

Explanation added due to comments:

1. This is where `\s*` finished matching and `\S+` starts matching:

   > ns.molot.ru.
2. Since `\S+` matches all characters except whitespace and the following `\r` `\n` `\t` `\f`, it will match these (bolded) and stop before the newline:

   > **ns.molot.ru.**
3. After that, the regex has `\.` so it tries to match a period, but there is no period left to match. `\S+` will then *backtrack* (give up one character from its match) and try again:

   > **ns.molot.ru**.
4. Now, after giving up the last character it matched, the regex tries to match `\.` again and succeeds.

   But if you have `\.` before the `\S+`, the regex will try to match the period first, when it's still here (at step 1):

   > ns.molot.ru.

   But since there's an `n` there, it won't match and the whole regex stops there.

Comment: Could you explain `(?<Value>\S+)\.` ?

Comment: @user1776231 Well, `\S+` matches all non-space characters (`\S` is literally the opposite of `\s`). `\S` is actually the character class `[^\r\n\t\f ]`, so it will never match newlines or carriage returns. The dot at the end causes `\S+` to give up the last period it matched, so that your capture group `Value` contains characters up to a period, without capturing it.

Comment: But shouldn't the order be `\.` and then `\S+`. Because first comes the dot and then the newline.

Comment: @user1776231 I cannot explain that in a comment, so I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way, change your pattern to:

```
(?<=nserver:\s*)(?<Value>.*)(?=\.\r?\n)
```

You must remove the pattern option singleline.